# 'R' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to

Tags: typescript-typings, typescript-generics, type-inference

How can I infer the return type of `R` based on the code bellow.

```
export type SequenceDefinition<S extends string> = {
  keys: S[] | Readonly<S[]>,
  actions: Record<S, <R>(data: SequenceData<S, SequenceDefinition<S>>) => R>
}

type SequenceData<S extends string, T extends SequenceDefinition<any>> = {
  get: (key: S) => ReturnType<T['actions'][S]>
}

export type SequenceCreatorFn = <S extends string>(config: SequenceDefinition<S>) => void;

export const sequence: SequenceCreatorFn = (config) => {
  console.log(config);
};

const result = sequence({
  keys: ['load', 'save', 'log'],
  actions: {
    load: () => {. // <- Error here
      return { a: 1, b: 2 };
    },
    save: (data) => { // <- Error here
      data.get('load');
      return true;
    },
    log: () => { // <- Error here
      return 1;
    }
  }
});
```

The error message is:

```
Type '() => { a: number; b: number; }' is not assignable to type '<R>(data: SequenceData<"load" | "save" | "log", SequenceDefinition<"load" | "save" | "log">>) => R'.
  Type '{ a: number; b: number; }' is not assignable to type 'R'.
    'R' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to '{ a: number; b: number; }'.
```

1. Typescript is returning error on the action method, unless I use `any` or `unknown` as return type.
2. I want the have a strong type definition of the `data.get` based on the previous interactions.

**Update 01**

I got a bit closer, but not there yet. Maybe you have an idea.

```
type TBaseSteps = Record<string, unknown>;

type SequenceDefinition<TSteps = TBaseSteps> = {
  keys: (keyof TSteps)[];
  steps: {
    [TKey in keyof TSteps]: (
      data: SequenceData<TSteps>
    ) => Promise<TSteps[TKey]>;
  };
};

type SequenceData<TSteps = TBaseSteps> = {
  get: <TKey extends keyof TSteps>(key: TKey) => Awaited<TSteps[TKey]>;
};

export const sequence = async <TSteps = TBaseSteps>(
  config: SequenceDefinition<TSteps>
): Promise<SequenceData<TSteps>> => {
  console.log(config);
  return undefined as any;
};

const result = await sequence({
  keys: ['load', 'save', 'refresh', 'log'],
  steps: {
    load: async () => {
      return { a: 1, b: 2 };
    },
    save: async (data) => {
      return true;
    },
    refresh: async () => {
      return 'refresh';
    },
    log: async (data) => {
      const load = data.get('load'); // <-- Type properly inferred
      const save = data.get('save'); // <-- Type unknown
      const refresh = data.get('refresh'); // <-- Type properly inferred, if add the parameter data to refresh step it becomes unknown

      return 1;
    },
  },
});

const load = result.get('load');
const save = result.get('save');
const refresh = result.get('refresh');
```

Answer (score 0):

Typescript cannot infer the type of R because it can be anything. If you take this function for example

```js
function test(
// This is the type of your sequence config
config: SequenceDefinition<"load" | "save" | "log">
){
config.actions.load()
}
```

you can see that going by just the definition of the input type, there is no way for typescript to know what load returns, conversly any function that has the 3 function load, save and log can be assigned to `SequenceDefinition<"load" | "save" | "log">`.
The solution is to make your type more discriminant so that for each action the function can only return a single type

```js
export type SequenceDefinition<Actions extends Record<string,unknown>> = {
  keys: (keyof Actions)[],
  actions:{
    [key in keyof Actions]: (data: SequenceData<Actions>) => Actions[key]
  } 
}

type SequenceData<Actions extends Record<string,unknown>> = {
  get: <Key extends keyof Actions>(key: Key) => Actions[Key]
}

export type SequenceCreatorFn = <Actions extends Record<string,unknown>>(config: SequenceDefinition<Actions>) => void;

export const sequence: SequenceCreatorFn = (config) => {
  console.log(config);
};

const result = sequence({
  keys: ['load', 'save', 'log'],
  actions: {
    load: () => { 
      return { a: 1, b: 2 };
    },
    save: (data) => { 
      data.get('load');
      return true;
    },
    log: () => { 
      return 1;
    }
  }
});
```

in this case `SequenceDefinition` is no longer defined by only the keys but also the values that the functions return

Comment: It works great, thanks! Only one thing seems a bit off. On the example above the `save` gets `data` as parameter and that makes `save` return type as unknown. 

I created a playground to show what I mean. https://stackblitz.com/edit/rdfwuo?file=index.ts&view=editor

Comment: Any ideas on how to fix it?

Comment: While toying around with it, i think the problem is the circular constraint in SequenceDefinition. If you your place `(data: SequenceData<Actions>) =>Actions[key]` with `() =>Actions[key]` the type is inferred correctly ( albeit breaking .get methods )
I think the simplest way to use this is to explicitly mention the generic parameter instead of having it inferred

```const result = sequence<{load: {a:number;b:number}; save:boolean; log: number}>({
...
```